# VSIX how to get current snapshot document name?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix

I have been trying to to create an extension that highlights specific line numbers for me in Visual Studio in the margins.

I manged to get my marking in the margins using predefined line number but for it to work properly I need to know what the current document FullName is (Path and filename)

After much googling I figured out how to do it with the sample code (which is not ideal)

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");

var activeDocument = dte.ActiveDocument;

var docName = activeDocument.Name;
var docFullName = activeDocument.FullName;
```

Now I know the problems here

- is that is for specific version bases on the text
- there is no way to select which instance (when running more than one VS)
- It seems to be very slow

I have a feeling I should be doing this with MEF  Attributes but the MS docs examples are so simple that they do not work for me. I scanned a few SO questions too and I just cannot get them to work. They mostly talk about `Services`.. which I do not have and have no idea how to get.

The rest of my code uses `SnapshotSpans` as in the example Extension of [Todo_Classification examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Todo_Classification) which is great if you do NOT need to know the file name.

I have never done any extensions development. Please can somebody help me do this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code to get a file from a snapshot without any dependencies.

```
    public string GetDocumentPath(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextSnapshot ts)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocument textDoc;
        bool rc = ts.TextBuffer.Properties.TryGetProperty(
            typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocument), out textDoc);
        if (rc && textDoc != null)
            return textDoc.FilePath;
        return null;
    }
```

If you don't mind adding `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text` to your project it will provide you with an extension method `Document GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges()` on the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Snapshot` class. (Plus many other Rosyln based helpers)

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

Document doc = span.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey that is quite some invaluable code you have provided there.. I am not sure where else that could be documented? I also found another post by somebody to use Rosylyn Code Analysis packages which gives us allot of extensions, particularly the `Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges()` provided in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text` - I suppose it is going to be a very similar code in that package you have just provided

Comment: I hope you do not mind I added the example to make your answer more complete. Thanks! +1